# Biopython - Big Discrepancy Calculating RNA melting Temperature over Literature

Tags: biopython

I experience big discrepancies when calculating ***melting temperature*** of **RNA 7-mers** with Biopython over values generated by a popular algorithm.

I tried the nearest neighbour algorithm with RNA and salt concentrations as described in a respective paper (thermodynamic table used as in paper below from: *Freier et al 1986*). Yet, the values largely differ (execute code below to see).
I tried all seven salt correction methods provided by Biopython, still I never get close to the values generated by siRNA design algorithm for the same 7-mers.

Can someone tell me how accurate Biopython's melting temperature nearest neighbour algorithm is? Especially for short oligomers like my 7-mers? Is there maybe something I am implementing wrong? Any suggestions?

Values derived from executing **sample input**:
http://sidirect2.rnai.jp/
Tm is given for the seed duplex of the *guide strand*: **bases 2-7**

**Literature:**
"*Thermodynamic  stability  and  Watson–Crick
base  pairing  in  the  seed  duplex  are  major
determinants  of  the  efficiency  of  the
siRNA-based  off-target  effect*"
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2602766/pdf/gkn902.pdf

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq  
from Bio.SeqUtils import MeltingTemp

test_list = [
('GGAUUUG', 21.5),
('CUCAUUG', 18.1),
('CAUAUUC', 8.7),
('UUUGAGU', 19.2),
('UUUUGAG', 12.2),
('GUUUCAA', 14.9),
('AGUUUCG', 19.7),
('GAAGUUU', 13.3)
]


for t in test_list:
    myseq = Seq(t[0])
    tm = MeltingTemp.Tm_NN(myseq, dnac1=100, Na=100,   nn_table=MeltingTemp.RNA_NN1, saltcorr=7)  # NN1 = Freier et al (1986)
    tm = round(tm, 1)  # round to one decimal
    print 'BioPython Tm: ' + str(tm) + '  siDirect Tm: ' + str(t[1])
```

Comment: move is ask: [http://biology.stackexchange.com/](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) ..... it will be more likely to reply

Comment: Or even BioStar: https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: OK. Thanks, Jose and cnluzon! I will move my question. I started here as I was most familiar with stackoverflow.

Comment: I posted here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/33032/biopython-big-discrepancy-calculating-rna-melting-temperature-over-literature

Comment: Also at Biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/140873/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered the question at [biology.stackexchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/33032/biopython-big-discrepancy-calculating-rna-melting-temperature-over-literature) and [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/140873/). In short: It seems that **siDirect** calculates the Tm wrong due to using a 1000fold higher primer concentration.